# what is the best way to return a json in an Ok () (status 200) of an Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core Web API project, I am doing this to build a json style:

```
    {
        "ok": true,
        "error": {
            "message": "el valor Terror ya existe"
        }
    }
```

with this code:

```
 message = $"el valor {message} ya existe";
 var new_json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ok = true, error = new { message = message } });
 return Ok(new_json);
```

the json is returned as plain text. how can I make it return as a json?

Comment: JSON *is* "plain text". If you mean the content type, remove the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` call and return the anonymous object

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core Web API framework? Please specify in your question

Comment: @CoolBots yes!!!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  solved, did not know that. then what is the purpose of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` ? I thought that with this a json was created

Comment: There is a lot of usage for that one, yavg, but for webapi, the framework takes care of that for you

Comment: Well, suppose you're writing a client that's a WPF app - it won't automatically serialize/deserialize anything... then you need `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` call prior to sending the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Web API framework auto-serializes the responses as JSON. So, you're manually serializing first - you get a `string`. That string gets serialized (as another `string`) - and sent over to the client... where you deserialize it... and get a `string`!

Remove the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` call, and just pass the JSON object (your *Model*, presumably) to the `Ok()` function:

```cs
message = $"el valor {message} ya existe";
var new_json = new { ok = true, error = new { message = message } };
return Ok(new_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
message = $"el valor {message} ya existe";
return Ok(new { 
  ok = true, 
  error = new { 
    message = message 
  } 
});
```